# Parse multiple subdirectories specified in multiple lists

Tags: python, file, directory, directory-structure

I have a directory structured as below:

```
|-- Transcripts
|   |-- [Time_n]
|   |   |-- [Group_n]
|   |   |   |-- file_1.txt
|   |   |   |-- ...
|   |   |   |-- file_n_n.txt
|   |...
|
```

To parse every file in all subdirectories, where there are multiple `Times` with multiple `Groups`, I would just use:

```
import glob

path = 'Transcripts/***/**/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path, recursive=True)
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

However, if I want to specify only certain `Times` and `Groups`, can I do this from `glob`, or can I only do it in the loop below?

Example collections:

```
times = ['Time1', 'Time3']
groups = ['Group2', 'Group4']
```

This should only loop through these subdirectories:

```
/Transcripts/Time1/Group2/
/Transcripts/Time1/Group4/
/Transcripts/Time3/Group2/
/Transcripts/Time3/Group4/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import glob
path = './Transcripts/Time[1,3]/Group[2,4]/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Output:

```
./Transcripts\Time1\Group2\file_1.txt
./Transcripts\Time1\Group2\file_2.txt
./Transcripts\Time1\Group4\file_1.txt
./Transcripts\Time1\Group4\file_2.txt
./Transcripts\Time3\Group2\file_1.txt
./Transcripts\Time3\Group2\file_2.txt
./Transcripts\Time3\Group4\file_1.txt
./Transcripts\Time3\Group4\file_2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a list for intended groups and intended directories.While looping through concat the group number or directory number as per your logic.

Comment: The question asks if I can do it above the loop level.

Comment: You can do it in both ways.Depends on how you implement .

Comment: Could you please show how to do it the other way, in addition? Thanks!